# Codeigniter Project Working Locally & on web Showing 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

hi my project works fine locally but when i try to run on shared hosting it gives 404 error my structure is as follows

Project structure

```
/public_html/mydomain.com
-content
   --asset
   --build
--case
--core
  --application
  --main
  --system
--lwyers
--setup
--subdomains

$config['base_url'] = 'http://mydomain.c-m/';
$config[‘uri_protocol’] = 'AUTO';
$config['content_url'] = 'http://mydomain.c-m/content/';
$config['index_page'] = '';


 htc access file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>code here
```

Pls guide me where I am doing wrong,

Answer (score 0):

please check your project's directory permission.
your directory must be have permission like this : rwx-rwx-rx

Comment: can u pls explain project is hosted on root of domain , did u mean to say i will change permission of domain folder or any other folder

Comment: what is your permission root of domain folder?

Comment: all permission are default permission shall i change permission to any specific folder